# Как правильно наследоваться от контейнера?

Tags: android, java

Создал класс, наследовался от SCrollView, добавляю через CustomView, в итоге View компонент отображается как View, а не как контейнер, то есть я добавить в него другой компонент не могу. Как быть?

Comment: 1. Все контейнеры также являются View, ибо они наследуются от VuewGroup, который наследуется от View.


2. Код в студию.

Comment: @Suvitruf, удивительно, но сейчас работает почему-то... А до этого ошибку выдавал, якобы это не вю груп, а прост вю.

Comment: @ANDRO просто я владею древней магией.